# Python3: Erro na função que tem dicionario

Tags: python

Estou com presente codigo dando erro na atribuição da variavel M, do dicionario.

Retornando o seguinte: `NameError: name 'm' is not defined`

Sou iniciante neste tipo de assunto.

**O objetivo dele** é retorna uma data por extenso.

```
data = input('Digite a data (DD/MM/AAAA): ')
def função_data(data, m):
    m = {
    "01":"janeiro",
    "02":"fevereiro",
    "03":"março",
    "04":"abril",
    "05":"maio",
    "06":"junho",
    "07":"julho",
    "08":"agosto",
    "09":"setembro",
    "10":"outubro",
    "11":"novembro",
    "12":"dezembro"}
    return data, m
print(função_data(f'{data[0:2]} de {m[0:3]} de {data[6:]}'))
```

Será necessario printa o nome antes do `return`, fiz isso porém sem sucesso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consertando o seu código:

```
meses = {
    "01":"janeiro",
    "02":"fevereiro",
    "03":"março",
    "04":"abril",
    "05":"maio",
    "06":"junho",
    "07":"julho",
    "08":"agosto",
    "09":"setembro",
    "10":"outubro",
    "11":"novembro",
    "12":"dezembro"
}

data = input('Digite a data (DD/MM/AAAA): ')

def função_data(d, m):
    return d[0:2], m[d[3:5]], d[6:]
    
dia, mes, ano = função_data(data, meses)
    
print(f'{dia} de {mes} de {ano}')
```

Se o objetivo é retornar uma data por extenso use o módulo [datetime](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/datetime.html).
Para retornar a data formatada em uma linguagem e cultura específica use o módulo [locale](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/locale.html#locale.getlocale)

```
import datetime as dt
import locale 

try:
   locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, locale.normalize('pt_BR.utf8'))
except locale.Error:
   print('Instale o módulo de línguagem adequado no seu Sistema Operacional.')

d= input('Digite a data (DD/MM/AAAA): ')
data = dt.datetime.strptime(d,"%d/%m/%Y")


print(data.strftime("%d de %B de %Y"))
```

Teste no Windows:
[image: Teste no Windows]
Teste no Linux:
[image: Teste no Linux]

Comment: Augusto, obrigado. Uma pergunta, você sempre que possivel procura resolução na documentação de algo semelhante quando esta programado? Faço isso, mas as vezes não encontro algo aproximado.

Comment: Sim, sempre procuro [a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html).